# SetExact permission

Tags: java, android

Hi im trying to set an exact intent so that my app will do a background work such as getting the last location of the user and sending his lat and lot to the api and show tomorrow's forecast as a notification.
for some reason
in this code im always in the else block, and my app isn't even showing in the alarms and reminders list, why is that ?
I cant turn the Allow permissions for alarms & reminders its grayed out...
that's the scheduling code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "This app requires the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission to function properly.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM)
            intent.data = Uri.fromParts("package", requireContext().packageName, null)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    }
```

thats my manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```